# Move 20,000 files from one directory sequentially and so on

Tags: bash, shell-script

What I am trying to accomplish is I have a directory with lets say 176,000 files. I want the script to split the 176,000 files into folders with lets say 20,000 files each and the last one containing the odd ball #. I would like to copy the files sequentially and keeping them in order alpha numerical. This is what I currently have but it seems to be missing something, the first 2 folders it creates are out of order, the other 3 folders it creates are sequential.

Bottom line, folder contains 176,000 files, script would move the first 20,000 into a folder called 'split' then takes the next 20,000 and so on, creating split2, split3, etc..

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir_size=20000
dir_name="split"
n=$((`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`/$dir_size+1))
for i in `seq 1 $n`;
do
    mkdir -p "$dir_name$i";
    find  .  -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -n -z |  head -n $dir_size |  xargs -i mv "{}" "$dir_name$i"
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make a list of your files (note that you cannot use `ls *` or `ls*.dpx` because this would create a command line with 176000 parameters to `ls`) and use `split` to split this list in chunks (files named `files.01`, `files.02`...)(the lone `-` is telling split to work on standard input).

```
ls | split -d --lines 20000 - files.
```

- For more stringent filtering, you can also use `find` as you did, piping output to `split` after a sort:

```
find . type f | sort | split -d --lines 20000 - files.
```

- Iterate the produced `files.*`, create the directory name using the numeric part, and then move the files:

```
for f in files.*  # iterate the files.*
do 
    dirname="/path/to/dir${f#*.}"  # generate directory name from numeric suffix
    mkdir -p "$dirname" # create the directory
    xargs mv -t "$dirname" < $f # move the files
done
```

Warning: untested, try on a small sample first.

If you have spaces in the file names use `find -print0`, `sort -z`, `split --separator '\0'` and `xargs -0`.

Comment: So what would the full syntax be? I'm fairly new with bash I just dont want to break the whole script :(  I know I'm close

Comment: See augmented answer

Comment: thanks man! in this line, how can I specify it to make the folders in the current working directory vs a specified path?     dirname="/path/to/dir${f#*.}"  # generate directory name from numeric suffix

Comment: Basically I want it to create the 'split' folders in the working directory

Comment: ` dirname="dirprefix${f#*.}"` where "dirprefix" is anything you like.

Comment: Thank you so much!